# DatePicker format issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use Kendo UI DatePicker

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.CalledInAt).Format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt").Value(DateTime.Now).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:205px" }))
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with entity framework.

when i try to submit a form it gives me the error. "The value '19/09/2013 04:08 AM' is not valid for CalledInAt"

If i change the format to dd/MM/yyyy then it works. something like below works.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.CalledInAt).Format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt").Value(DateTime.Now).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:205px" }))
```

what would be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the culture in web config that match with date format.

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-AU" />
```

See this link  [ASP.NET Date time support for different cultures](http://maheshde.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/aspnet-date-time-support-for-different.html)