# MVC Validation to accept DateTime in ddMMyyyy format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I just want to accept Date in ddMMyyyy format while submiting. But its gives an error like

> The field FromDate must be a date.

[image]

But, When I put date in MMddyyyy it accepts pkkttrfg roperly. 
My Model is

```
public class CompareModel 
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime TODate { get; set; }

}
```

My View Part is

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TODate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TODate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TODate)
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can look at using jquery globalize or add a method to the `$.validator` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) - note that solution is for the jquery ui datepicker but could be adjusted for a standard textbox (e.g. split the value into its components, construct a new javascript `Date()` object and test its valid)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is behind the scenes it uses javascript to validate this and you need to overwrite this.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('date',
    function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }

        var ok = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    });
});
```

Which was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14081487/537674)

Comment: Where do I put this? Thanks.  I will upvote once I get it working.

Comment: This requires jquery-ui to work, but is the best answer as it actually fixes the problem

Answer (score 4):

Just try adding

```
 <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
</System.web>
```

Its work for me with same issue

Answer (score 1):

same kind of question i answer before 
[DatePicker format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893352/datepicker-format-issue/18893547#18893547)

Try to set the culture in web config that match with date format.

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-AU" />
```

See this link ASP.NET Date time support for different cultures

http://maheshde.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/aspnet-date-time-support-for-different.html